# sorting a list and separating the different features

Tags: python

So I am given a list and I am supposed to sort it down into two lists, one with the names of the companies and one with the prices in a nested list.

```
['Acer 481242.74\n', 'Beko 966071.86\n', 'Cemex 187242.16\n', 'Datsun    748502.91\n', 'Equifax 146517.59\n', 'Gerdau 898579.89\n', 'Haribo 265333.85\n']
```

I used the following code to separate the names properly:

```
print('\n'.join(data))
namelist = [i.split(' ', 1)[0] for i in data]
print(namelist)
```

But now it wants me to seperate all the prices from the list and put them in a single list nested together and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *nested together*? Perhaps you could add the expected output to your question, for the given input?

Answer (score 2):

To build two separate lists, just use a regular loop:

```
names = []
prices = []
for entry in data:
    name, price = entry.split()
    names.append(name)
    prices.append(price)
```

If you needed the entries together in one list, each entry a list containing the name and the price separately, just split in a list comprehension like you did, but don't pick one or the other value from the result:

```
names_and_prices = [entry.split() for entry in data]
```

I used `str.split()` without arguments to split on *arbitrary* whitespace. This assumes you always have exactly two entries in your strings. You can still limit the split, but then use `None` as the first argument, and strip the line beforehand to get rid of the `\n` separately:

```
names_and_prices = [entry.strip().split(None, 1) for entry in data]
```

Demo for the 'nested' approach:

```
>>> data = ['Acer 481242.74\n', 'Beko 966071.86\n', 'Cemex 187242.16\n', 'Datsun    748502.91\n', 'Equifax 146517.59\n', 'Gerdau 898579.89\n', 'Haribo 265333.85\n']
>>> [entry.split() for entry in data]
[['Acer', '481242.74'], ['Beko', '966071.86'], ['Cemex', '187242.16'], ['Datsun', '748502.91'], ['Equifax', '146517.59'], ['Gerdau', '898579.89'], ['Haribo', '265333.85']]
```

Answer (score 0):

`split()` is the right approach, as it will give you everything you need if you don't limit it to just one split (the `, 1)` in your code). If you provide no arguments to it at all, it'll split on any size of whitespace.

```
>>> data = ['Acer 481242.74\n', 'Beko 966071.86\n', 'Cemex 187242.16\n', 'Datsun    748502.91\n', 'Equifax 146517.59\n', 'Gerdau 898579.89\n', 'Haribo 265333.85\n']
>>> nested_list = [i.split() for i in data]
>>> nested_list
[['Acer', '481242.74'], ['Beko', '966071.86'], ['Cemex', '187242.16'], ['Datsun', '748502.91'], ['Equifax', '146517.59'], ['Gerdau', '898579.89'], ['Haribo', '265333.85']]
>>> print(*nested_list, sep='\n')
['Acer', '481242.74']
['Beko', '966071.86']
['Cemex', '187242.16']
['Datsun', '748502.91']
['Equifax', '146517.59']
['Gerdau', '898579.89']
['Haribo', '265333.85']
```